# Google Analytics - Track application Id

Tags: variables, google-analytics, analytics, tracking

I've got an application form on my website which when successfully completed, the data is added to the database and a unique applicationId is given to each application. I want to track this applicationId in Google Analytics so tried adding a custom variable on the final step of the application form which passes in the applicationId as the value, however it doesn't seem to be tracking accurately. Is a custom variable the best method?

Here is my analytics:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www."); document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E")); </script>

<script type="text/javascript"> try { var pageTracker =
_gat._getTracker("UA-xxxxxxx-x");
    pageTracker._setDomainName('xx.co.uk'); 
<?php if($_SESSION['application'] && $_SESSION['application']->getStage() == 8){
    echo 'pageTracker._setCustomVar(3, "applicationId", "'.$_SESSION['application']->applicationId.'");'; 
}?>

    pageTracker._trackPageview(); 
} catch(err) {}</script>
```

Comment: You should update to the asynchronous tracking code. As to you question, storing user identifiable data in Analytics is a violation of Googles' terms of service so you shouldn't to this.

Comment: Thanks, I will be updating to asynchronous asap. It's not really user identifiable data as the user has a separate application number, it's more of a unique identifier for us to track where they have come from.